# How to "sam package" using AES256 encryption?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-sam-cli, aws-sam

From [here](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/HOWTO.md) I see the syntax:

```
sam package \
    --template-file /path_to_template/template.yaml \
    --s3-bucket bucket-name \
    --s3-prefix appname/branchname/version
    --output-template-file packaged-template.yaml
```

or

```
   aws cloudformation package \
    --template-file /path_to_template/template.yaml \
    --s3-bucket bucket-name \
    --s3-prefix appname/branchname/version
    --output-template-file packaged-template.yaml
```

---

but the s3 policy forces the client to mention server side encryption algo `AES256`.

```
 aws s3 cp file s3://some-bucket --sse AES256
```

What is the syntax to `sam package` encrypted artifact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to specify `--sse AES256` in your call. SAM (CloudFormation) `package` command automatically sends `x-amz-server-side-encryption: AES256` header so if your bucket requires default S3 encryption for `s3:putObject` (denies put requests based on following condition)

```
"Condition": {
  "StringNotEquals": {
    "s3:x-amz-server-side-encryption": "AES256"
  }
}
```

then this requirement is implicitly satisfied. If your bucket policy requires usage of a specific KMS key instead then you can pass KMS key id via optional flag: `--kms-key-id <value>`

Comment: Supple... How to make sure that artifact copied to s3 has custom name?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to give custom name to the artifact.

Comment: `--s3-prefix` only allows you to specify "folder" structure or prefix path but not the actual name of file

Comment: Related question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57121977/why-sam-package-publishes-the-artifacts-to-bucket